# How to mute BluetoothDevice logs?

Tags: android, bluetooth

In my app that uses bluetooth, the logs become flooded with probably hundreds of "D/BluetoothDevice: mAddress: (address)" lines. Assuming I can ignore them, how can I filter out these lines?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this has been resolved for a 'future release' of Android (here's hoping it's Oreo). See the issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37088105

There are some regex you may be able to use to get your logcat to skip/fold/ignore those events, perhaps the github issue (at https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/issues/35) raised for Estimote beacon scanning may help?

Unfortunately it doesn't resolve anything for existing releases of Android tho, looks like we'll be stuck with it :(